# Geo location - JS vs JSON

Tags: javascript, json, geolocation, jsonp, geocoding

I am tryign to obtain the geolocation of the user browsing using maxmind's free service
http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js

```
jQuery.getScript('http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js', function() 
{
    var country = geoip_city();
    console.log("Your location is: " + country);
});
```

However, outputting javascript code instead of a json seems like a bit of a problem, since it evals the code from a site outside your control. What would be the best practice to handle such scenarios?

Comment: From a security perspective, how is eval'ing code from another site any different to including it in a script element? Both will execute the code in a context under your control ([ECMA-262 §10.4.2 Entering Eval Code](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2))

Answer (score 0):

This will show user's city.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(geoip_city());
</script>
```